# CSS3 transition working one way but not the other

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a `<div>` that is conditionaly has one of either two classes -

```
ng-class="{'visible': sidebarShown, 'hidden': !sidebarShown}"
```

The initial class will always be `hidden`, and when `visible` replaces that class the `width`, `left` and `opacity` properties are all animated using a CSS3 transition.

However, when the `hidden` class replcaes `visible` the animation is not reversed, and instaed the new values for all three properties are switched to instantly.

I've tried adding the `transition` property to the styles for both `.visible` and `.hidden`, as well as to each individually, but in all cases only the `visible` animation works.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Relevant HTML**

```
<div id="modal" data-ng-if="isMobile"
                data-ng-class="{'visible': sidebarShown, 'hidden': !sidebarShown}">
</div>
```

---

**CSS for `#modal.hidden` and `#madal.visible`**

```
.mobile #modal{
    position:   absolute;
}
.mobile #modal.hidden{
    left:       0;
    opacity:    0;
    width:      100%;
}
.mobile #modal.visible{
    background-color:   #000000;
    height:             100%;
    left:               271px;
    opacity:            0.8;
    right:              0;
    width:              calc(100% - 271px);
    z-index:            99;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition:         all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

---

## Further attemtps

I've now discovered that an initial missing `height` was the issue.  The code below still only works one way.

What I need -

```
.mobile #modal.hidden  { height: 0; }
.mobile #modal.visible { height: 100%; }
```

When transitioning from `.hidden` to `.visible` the vaule of `height` should change instantly.  However, going the other way `height` should transition after a delay of `0.5s`, allowing for the other animations to finish.  I've come up with the below code, but it's still not quite there.

```
.mobile #modal{
    left:               0;
    opacity:            0;
    position:           absolute;
    width:              100%;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out,
                        opacity 0.5s ease-in-out,
                        width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition:         left 0.5s ease-in-out,
                        opacity 0.5s ease-in-out,
                        width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.mobile #modal.hidden{
    height:             0;
    -webkit-transition: height 0 ease-in-out 0.5s;
    transition:         height 0 ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.mobile #modal.visible{
    background-color:   #000000;
    height:             100%;
    left:               271px;
    opacity:            0.8;
    right:              0;
    width:              calc(100% - 271px);
    z-index:            99;
}
```

Comment: Try to put the `transition` rules on `.mobile #modal` instead of `.mobile #modal.visible`.

Comment: transition should be set once  on the default, seems to be like #modal here :). else on every rule but redondant

Comment: Thnks for the suggestions, but that does not work either.  I have also tried removing `.mobile #modal.hidden` entirly (placing the properties in to `.mobile #modal`), but that fails as well.

Comment: I just played around with your CSS, and got something similar to *Attempt 2* working: https://jsfiddle.net/v2b5e9d3/

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister - Thanks, that helps.  I've now discovered that this issue was that I was missing `height` from `.mobile #modal`. However, that raises another issue; I must transition the height for `0` to `100%` instantly when `.visible` replaces `.hidden`, but then transition after `0.5s` when `.hidden` replaces `.visible`.  I've updated my question to show this, as I now can't get this working.

Comment: Ah, finally I've got it.  No need to worry about changing the height, that can stay at 100%.  Instead, I've just added `z-inded: -1` as an initial value in `.mobile #modal` and it's working as required.  Thanks for your comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guided by the comment posted by **@MaximillianLaumeister** I established that the problem was that no initial height value was defined.

I then tried to transition that value as well, but in the end the solution was to simply "hide" `#modal` by setting `z-index: -1;`.

As the transition goes form 99 to -1 (in 0.5s), `.mobile #modal` is essentially visible throughout the transition, only disappearing behind the other content approx 0.005s before the end).

```
.mobile #modal{
    height:             100%;
    left:               0;
    opacity:            0;
    position:           absolute;
    width:              100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition:         all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index:            -1;
}
.mobile #modal.visible{
    background-color:   #000000;
    height:             100%;
    left:               271px;
    opacity:            0.8;
    right:              0;
    width:              calc(100% - 271px);
    z-index:            99;
}
```